# Rails console with Pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, pry

I've set pry to load in place of irb when I enter rails console. I cannot find the page or remember how to bring it back to the default behavior as it seems to be interfering with my Rubymine debugger. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I just found the issue, pry-rails gem. Forgot that its purpose is to make 'rails console' to open pry instead.

Answer (score 4):

You may have modified your `~/.irbrc` to start pry when IRB is loaded. Check there first.

Rails hooks into the application by loading your environment. To load your rails application into a pry session try this: `pry -I . -r config/environment`

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this page?

http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2011/08/23/replace-the-rails-console-with-pry

The page (now dead) contained this code, which could be what is keeping Pry running instead of IRB:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  silence_warnings do
    begin
      require 'pry'
      IRB = Pry
    rescue LoadError
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a dead link.